# Обращение с личными местоимениями. Нужно ли ставить запятую

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, обращение

Нужна ли запятая в обращениях перед **Ты / Вы**?

**Слышь ты** / **Слушай ты** / **Эй ты** / **Послушай ты** / **Послушайте вы**

Слышь(,) ты, Витя, хватит стучать по ночам

Слушай(,) ты, сосед, задолбала орать по ночам сигнализация на твоей машине.

Эй(,) ты, Костя, ты "домашку" по математике сделал?

Послушай(,) ты, приятель, когда уже приставку мне вернёшь?

Послушайте(,) вы, Фёдор Николаевич, сделайте так, как вы считаете, будет правильно, а потом уже критикуйте других.